# Как заставить firebug корректно выводить русский текст в консоль?

Tags: javascript, кодировка, firefox, firebug

код:

```
<script>
    var s = "Русский текст";

    console.log(s);
</script>
```

а в консоле firebug крякозяблы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кодировка у документа какая?

Comment: по умолчанию (точно не знаю), скрипт написан без применения тегов <head> и тд

Comment: Есть такое чувство, что само содержимое скрипта в cp1251. Попробуйте пересохранить в UTF без BOM и посмотреть что будет.

Answer (score 2):

вопрос решается подстановкой тега `<meta>`:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var s = "Русский текст";

    console.log(s);
</script>
</body>
```

> Результат:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]